# The percentage of a number within an interval (range of numbers)?

Tags: interval-arithmetic

How can I find the percentage of a number in a range of numbers.
Let's say the range of numbers are 600-800, so if 600 is 0% and 800 is 100% then how can I find what percentage is 732 in that range of numbers?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Subtract $600$ from everything. You're now left with "What percentage is $132$ of $200$?" Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: If the distribution is uniform, then you may use the methods shown below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to know, essentially, how far $732$ is on the way from $600$ to $800$.  The range—the extent of the possible numbers—is $800-600 = 200$, so the percentages are relative to that.  $732-600 = 132$, so the percentage is

$$
\frac{132}{200} = 0.66 = 66\%
$$

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

$\frac{X - 600}{800 - 600} × 100$

'X' is number between 600 to 800.