# Calculate upper range of two numbers given a lower number, a value in the range and the percentage it represents

Tags: percentages

A common practice in some enterprises is to not advise employees of the full salary range for their position. The policy is to often give the lower end of the salary range for their position, a percentage which represents where they sit within the range, their salary but not the figure representing the upper end of the salary range.

As a people leader in an enterprise this seems a little myopic as anyone who's a little smarter at maths than me should have no problem calculating the upper figure.

So in a vein similar to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121174/the-percentage-of-a-number-within-an-interval-range-of-numbers?newreg=2b42f50388b141bfb19a43b052f1c0a6). If I have a range of two numbers 
where

*l* is the lower number in the range
*v* is value within the range
*p* represents the percentage within that range
*u* is the unknown upper number in the range

If *l* = 10, *v* = 15 and *p* = 50% how do I calculate *u*?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and show what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the downvote :(, since I didn't know where to start, I had nothing to show.

Comment: Didn't you understand the solutions in the post that you linked?

Comment: I sure did (mostly), I just didn't know how to get it to work in reverse

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Subtracting $10$ from $l$ and $v$ gives $0$ and $15$.

Now $0$ is $0 \%$ of the range, and $5$ is $50 \%$ of the range. You can first find that $1 \%$ of the range is $\frac{5}{50}$, so the maximum value of the range at $100 \%$ will be $\frac{5}{50} \cdot 100$.

Now you just need to add $10$ back.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it, but I'm not sure why I need to subtract 10 from *l* which equates to *l* - *l*. Using your suggestion I came up with the following excel formula *=(v-l)/p+l*, which seems to work for a variety of numbers so far.

Comment: Yes, that formula is correct. If $v-l$ is $50 \%$ (or however many percent you have), dividing by that same $50 \%$ will give you $1$ or $100 \%$ of the range, which you can add onto the lower number to get the upper number.

Comment: In the solution, we subtract $l$ so that $0$ is $0 \%$ of the range, and the numbers are proportional to what percentage of the range they are in. This makes scaling the numbers up to $100 \%$ easier.